# redis set default Sliding Expiration in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redis

I'm installed Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis in ASP.NET Core 7, and I'm trying to set default SlidingExpiration in `program.cs`:

[image]

I'm not seeing any option for this even in `configurationOptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis Cache does not support setting the global expiration time by default.

Check the source code of `RedisCacheOptions`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration options for <see cref="RedisCache"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class RedisCacheOptions : IOptions<RedisCacheOptions>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The configuration used to connect to Redis.
        /// </summary>
        public string Configuration { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The configuration used to connect to Redis.
        /// This is preferred over Configuration.
        /// </summary>
        public ConfigurationOptions ConfigurationOptions { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a delegate to create the ConnectionMultiplexer instance.
        /// </summary>
        public Func<Task<IConnectionMultiplexer>> ConnectionMultiplexerFactory { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Redis instance name.
        /// </summary>
        public string InstanceName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Redis profiling session
        /// </summary>
        public Func<ProfilingSession> ProfilingSession { get; set; }

        RedisCacheOptions IOptions<RedisCacheOptions>.Value
        {
            get { return this; }
        }
    }
```

It does not provide  properties like:

```
public TimeSpan DefaultSlidingExpiration { get; set; }

public TimeSpan? ExpiredItemsDeletionInterval { get; set; }
```

for user to set default expiration time.

One simple method is custom set cache method with default expiration.

```
public static  class Test
    {
        public static Task SetdefaultStringAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, string value,  CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            }
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
            }

            //set default Sliding Expiration
            var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            
            return cache.SetAsync(key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), options, token);
        }
    }
```

Now, When you use this custom method, It will set default Sliding Expiration for 5 second.